# Is it safe to track trunk in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm currently using `Django 1.1 beta` for some personal projects, and plan to start messing arround with the trunk to see the new stuff under the hood. But I might start using it on a professional basis, and I'd need to know if `trunk` is stable enough for using in production, or I should stick to 1.0 for mission critical systems.

### Edit

Putting all the information in answer for correctness.

Comment: You can get Django 1.1 now as it will be GA in a few days (assuming no new bugs is introduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [Django 1.1](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.1-rc-1/) is [one step closer to being released](http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2009/jul/21/rc/), as [RC1 is available for download](http://www.djangoproject.com/download/).

With that out of the way, I've found some useful things.

- If you are planning following this project, you should keep an eye in the [Django deprecation timeline](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#internals-deprecation), along the [Django deprecation policy](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/release-process/#internal-release-deprecation-policy).
- Another important place to look, is the [API Stability](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/api-stability/#misc-api-stability) page of [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/).
- Keep an eye on the [django-users mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users), as well as the [django-developer mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers).

Am I missing something I should be looking too?

### Edit

[Django 1.1 was released](http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2009/jul/29/1-point-1/)!!! You can [download it **right now**](http://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.1/tarball/)! :)

The question remains if `trunk` following is not recommended (once upon a time, *Django didn't have releases*, you only had `head` of `trunk`)

---

Acording to the tech team at [The Onion](http://www.theonion.com), which [has migrated from Drupal to Django](http://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/bhvhz/the_onion_uses_django_and_why_it_matters_to_us/), [Django trunk is extremely stable](http://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/bhvhz/the_onion_uses_django_and_why_it_matters_to_us/c0mv32r).

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't pull Django trunk *every* day, sometimes there are big commits that might break some things on your site. Also it depends what features you use, the new ones will of cause be a bit more buggy than older features. But all in all there shouldn't be a problem using trunk for production. You just need to be careful when updating to latest revision.

You could for example set up a new virtual environment to test, before updating the live site. There are many ways to do something simelar, but I will let you take your pick.

Comment: So a two phase update is important. I should have a development server to test changes before doing the upgrade, just as if it were my own code base. I know this is basic, but I gess should be added.

Comment: You can always run separate instances on the same server to test first, depending on your resources, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've done a good job of gathering the right links in the question.  The only links I would add are:

- http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/BackwardsIncompatibleChanges
- http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/FutureBackwardsIncompatibleChanges

The first is for anyone still on a pre 1.0 release and wondering about the upgrade path, even to the trunk.  The second is a work in progress it seems, and may be updated as things progress toward the 2.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

As with the trunk of any software project, it's only as stable as the people commiting things test for. Typically this is probably pretty stable, but you need to be aware that if you get caught with a 'bad' version (which can happen), your site/s just might come down over it temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I've read in multiple places (in the documentation here: http://www.djangoproject.com/download/ (see the side bar) and from the project's lead developers in a book of theirs) that it's fine to use the trunk. Many of their own developers use trunk for their sites and so they have incentive to keep it stable.

Recently, however, they mentioned that the 1.1 RC along with any other pre-release packages should not be used for production ( http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2009/jul/21/rc/ ) so the signals are somewhat mixed.

That said, my personal feeling is that the trunk is very stable most of the time but as with any code you haven't used before you should run it through its paces before deploying anything.

As the other posters said though: the choice is ultimately yours to make based on your best judgement.