# Django Trunk Stability

Tags: django

How stable is the Django trunk?

I am getting this issue today from updating my Django trunk:

```
    403 Forbidden

    CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

    More information is available with DEBUG=True.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your specific question on stability of Django trunk, my experience has been generally positive.  Though an occasional issue crops up, it's usually fixed pretty quickly.  If you plan on tracking trunk, I'd recommend monitoring the mailing lists, especially for big, potentially de-stabilizing changes (also, see "[Is it safe to track trunk in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165631/is-it-safe-to-track-trunk-in-django)"), and for any potential backwards compatibility issues.

As for your CSRF verification failure, there have been [recent changes to the CSRF middleware](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers/browse_thread/thread/ac771d10d58340cb) that you may need to accommodate in your code.  See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) (Note the "How to use it" section is tagged with "Changed in Django Development version") which includes information on a template tag that you'll likely need to include in your template.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that no trunk is stable.

Comment: I might have to agree with this statement, but I would say that no trunk is "ROCK SOLID". Issues to come up from time to time with it.